# jooq + jackson fails to convert json to pojo due to case sensitivity

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

The following code fails:

```
    final var account = dc.select(ACCOUNT.asterisk())
            .from(ACCOUNT)
            .limit(1)
            .forJSON().path().withoutArrayWrapper()
            .fetchOneInto(Account.class);
```

The error message is like:

> Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "FIRSTNAME" ... known properties: ... "firstname"
> ...

Jackson seems to have problems mapping the upper case column FIRSTNAME into the pojo's lowercase field "firstname" (and similar for all other fields). I am using the generated classes. How can I fix it while still using json?

The jooq version is 3.16 and the database is oracle.

Comment: Nice to see SQL Server's `FOR JSON` syntax usage with Oracle. What's the rationale? Are you supporting both RDBMS, or do you find that syntax to be easier than the Oracle/standard SQL one?

Comment: To be honest – I haven't tried anything else so far.

Comment: This one seems to work but has the same LocalDateTime issue. But the markdown does not seem to work.

```
    final var jsonEntries = Stream.of(ACCOUNT.fields())
            .map(field -> jsonEntry(field.getName().toLowerCase(), field))
            .collect(toUnmodifiableList());
    final var oracle = dc.select(jsonObject(jsonEntries))
            .from(ACCOUNT)
            .limit(1)
            .fetchOneInto(Account.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixing the Jackson mapping use-case

In your particular query, you could auto-alias all columns to their lower case equivalent, e.g.:

```java
final var account = 
    dc.select(Stream
          .of(ACCOUNT.fields())
          .map(f -> f.as(f.getName().toLowerCase()))
          .toList())
      .from(ACCOUNT)
      .limit(1)
      .forJSON().path().withoutArrayWrapper()
      .fetchOneInto(Account.class);
```

#### Avoiding the use-case entirely

However, given your particular query, I don't really see the point of passing through the JSON serialisation only to benefit from a third party mapper. Why not use jOOQ for that as well?

```java
final var account = 
    dc.selectFrom(ACCOUNT)
      .limit(1)
      .fetchOneInto(Account.class);
```

Or, if `Account` is an immutable class (e.g. a Java record), why not use type safe mapping like this:

```java
final var account = 
    dc.selectFrom(ACCOUNT)
      .limit(1)
      .fetchOne(Records.mapping(Account::new));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It helps but I get a different error now: "Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling". The datetype module is not supported. Is there a way to configure this jackson module for jooq's ObjectMapper? Or setting a preconfigured ObjectMapper?

Comment: @bollin: Given your comment *"To be honest – I haven't tried anything else so far."*, let me suggest something much better to you, instead of going down that rabbit hole of tweaking the `ConverterProvider` that you can see here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12388

Comment: The answer does not really resolve my problem because I oversimplified my question in the first place in order to avoid too much complexity. I am accepting the answer anyway. My real solution is at least inspired by this answer.

Comment: @bollin: If you think that someone else could profit from your *actual* question and answer, you could provide both in a new question *and* answer, as that is being encouraged on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions